# Can a webservice class inherit asp.net page class

Tags: asp.net, web-services, inheritance, asmx, multiple-inheritance

i have an application consisting of two asp.net projects. And i have have a BasePage which inherits `System.Web.UI.Page` and have the class some core logic which i require in all of my pages(Implemented in `BasePage.cs`). So all my pages inherit this `BasePage.cs` . Now can an Webservice inherit the same class apart from the normal webservice class `System.Web.Services.WebService`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multiple inheritance is not supported in the .NET framework. And even if it was, this kind of implementation would hardly be called good practice.

All methods that are called by the web pages as well as the webservice pages should be put into extra classes.

Answer (score 2):

Any logic that could be used both by a web page and by a web service should be in a separate class that can be used by both. Such logic must not depend on being part of a UI.

Put it into a static class and have both the service and the pages use it.

Answer (score 0):

Views and services should be completely separate.  Services should not know anything about pages.  I would say you should not if you could.

Answer (score 0):

Normally every asp.net web page inherit  "System.Web.UI.Page".
But in your case u have base class that class inherits "System.Web.UI.Page"  then you use that base class for all asp.net web page no issues.
Web service's base class is "System.Web.Services.WebService" so whenever you use web service you should inherit this web service's class. You cannot use your base class(BasePage.cs) to your web service.